# How do I fix edit/fix my very very bad questions?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban, editing-help

I am currently on a question ban, and till my next question comes, I am focused more on the review queue (*honestly I don't know what I would do if I didn't have that*) and SEDE queries to try to grasp the answers to my SO life questions.

So I've made some queries to help me understand which questions did do solid, and why some didn't, even though they had been mostly tested, formatted, etc.

*Here is the query that calculates the voting per view on questions*:

> https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1105266?UserId=3142882#graph

*Here is the query that gets the posts per time span*:

> https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1105284?StartYear=2019&StartMonth=5&ToYear=2019&ToMonth=8&UserId=3142882

These queries helped me find the questions that had positive and negative impact on the community. My wish is to understand how can I ask questions that will have the most impact, and what topics are considered relevant.

### Good questions examples:

- [Tkinter frame windows managing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815151/manage-different-tkinter-frames-within-tk-in-python) Not answered
- [MuLaw decompression/compression for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085735/python-u-law-mulaw-wave-decompression-to-raw-wave-signal) Self accepted answered, 2K views
- [Valid load with binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951452/value-of-crlf-cr-chunk-in-png) Answered

### Bad Questions examples:

- [Ajax failed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893513/ajax-smaller-compact-code-console-log-not-showing) I just accepted the answer after many years of being dormant. I see the failure in asking the question, but I don't know how to fix it.
- [Memset re-invention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57429807/c-recreate-memset-with-pointers-and-address-of-operators) Good intentions bad idea. Was self accepted answered
- [Custom binary file handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671728/how-to-write-custom-binary-file-handler-in-c-with-serialisation-of-custom-obje) Still under construction. Similar concept as *Memset question*, and self accepted Answered.

---

The conclusion - many of the questions that have high downvotes via view per question ratio are questions that either failed due to the language (terminology) an issue from my side, or they failed due to good intentions but bad (or to broad) implementations.

I would like to edit those *bad questions* to be more like *good questions* and help myself out of the question ban.

**But the issue I am facing is that**: some of those questions are so bad that I don't know how to approach editing them, and other are too broad that if I split them across multiple linking questions I will lose all those answers/suggestions people have made over time - and that the fact that even deleted questions count in decision of banning, so deleting them is out of the question.

I need a fresh set of eyes, and more experienced users (willing and patient) that can clearly pinpoint major flaws in questions that I don't see (at their own or at least tell me that I need to put that puppy down).

This is something I am not able to do myself, therefore how do I fix edit/fix my very very bad questions?

Comment: Looking at your questions I'm a *little* surprised you have a question ban, I'm sure there are much worse askers than you. You've asked 24 questions with only 5 with a negative score and 8 with a positive score. Are you sure you haven't already got some deleted questions?

Comment: "honestly I don't know what I would do if I didn't have that" I suggest reading a book. Maybe a nice walk? ;).

Comment: I left a comment on the tkinter question asking for some clarification. The question is a little unclear but I think I can see what you're fundamentally asking for.

Comment: I edited your [Ajax failed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893513/ajax-smaller-compact-code-console-log-not-showing) for spelling, grammar, and formatting. You might be surprised at how often those things matter when presenting a question. Take a look at [the diff](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32893513/revisions) and take what you can from it. Note that questions asking to make code "smaller" are rarely taken very well here. This isn't [codegolf.se] and it's not [codereview.se] (although questions are often on-topic on both sites).

Comment: Thank you all. @NickA I do have deleted questions, 2 community deleted questions so far. I plan to learn from this at try to tackle those :D And even then perhaps ask for help depending on how lost i feel in my own thoughts.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ahaha :D I do that often! :D And ... something else that isn't for public knowledge. :P But i feel i need to stay in touch here, so i am forced to watch rep counter all the time out of need :D

Comment: @HereticMonkey, the Ajax question wasn't about making code smaller, it was an error that resulted from me making code smaller. Refactoring silent error is what I would call it if i had a name for that. I had code that worked perfectly, then i redid it and made it "smaller" and then job that was supposed to be done   - wasn't, but no error was shown.

Comment: Well, that wasn't clear from the text, which starts, "I need to make my code smaller and more compact". As the first sentence of the question, I think most people would think, "This OP wants to make their code smaller and more compact" :). I understand, I often think I'm saying something with utmost clarity and brilliance only to see people's eyes glazing over or squinting. Good luck!

Comment: I share your frustrations. There's at least three people *today* that have expressed concerns with legalistic and very frustrating nature/culture of this site as well. Ugh. I feel you @Danilo. Sorry for your negative experience as well. I've had the same... They need to fix some core problems here..

Comment: @Heretic Thanks for pointing out. I've must've read that question an bunch of times and it seemed that I naturally switched to that text being logical to me. I really helped. It doesn't matter if it gets up votes now. It matters that I made it clear even if it was a fluke. And thank all of you guys who up voted my previous answers mentioned here. I appreciate it, and don't get me wrong I would also like to continue to improve myself not to get in this thing again.

Comment: @sofrs I think I've passed the frustration part. It was bad for me. Sure there was some animosity in the start, and sometimes I did view straight on no bullshit answer as an offensive, and sometimes there was offensive content. But being angry on others didn't help my case at all or give me credibility to state my case. And once I started being more self focused and improving myself more I jumped over 100 in rep in 2 weeks and got some heft behind my name.

Comment: @sfors For some people, it is "keeping score", BUT... Reputation has other, more useful connotations: 1) It gives people an indication as to whether someone's contributions on the site have been consistently useful, whether the information they put in a comment or question has a good chance of being correct; 2) it means the person has spent enough time on the site to understand how it works. This, in turn, means they can be trusted by the site with curator duties, should they wish to contribute to maintaining site quality. Editing questions' tags so that the right people see them, for example.

Comment: @EthanField Hi mate! :D thanks for the time and patience you spend on me. I think that perhaps it would be beneficial to continue the whole `tkinter frame` discussion here, where you can give an answer with topics/bulletins of which are unclear from the question. I am even open to joining a chat room if it seems that my language incoherence will be an issue.